# sleep internal hdd forever

Tags: hard-drive, unmount

I have an internal hdd what I just rarely use under ubuntu, I want to send the hdd to sleep mode but after 10 minutes it is always wake up.

- I turned off in the disks to auto mount this drive
- after that I comment out this hdd from /etc/fstab

I send the hdd in sleep mode with this command : sudo hdparm -Y /dev/sdb, but after 10 minutes it is starts to spinning.

I've tried these :

- systemctl mask udisks2
- service rsync stop
- service udev stop

but still every 10 minutes it is starts spinning.

my log contains these lines in every 10 minutes :

[ 6607.762534] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 6610.626270] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133

What should I do to avoid I have to use the hdparm command in every 10 minutes?

Comment: This is an *internal* hard disk?

Comment: Yes. sorry I didn't mentioned that.

Comment: I've modified the title to make it more clear.

Comment: I’d revert those changes you’ve tried. They could give you a bunch of problems. Have you tried udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdX ? That should achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you! It seems its working!